# How can I interface graphical lcd with raspberry pi with yocto build image

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto

I am newbie to yocto world, learning and trying to develop small projects.
I want to interface graphical lcd with raspberry pi 3, what interface should I use?
I have build a yocto image for raspberry pi and running on it.
What changes do I need to make in yocto image to display something on glcd.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you will have to read the specification of the lcd you have chosen. This way you will be able to see if it is LVDS, RGB, etc as well as calculate the timings according to your requirements so that the display works as expected. [Here](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001945-13/reference/yocto/r_an_adding_custom_display.htm) is some information.

Once you have that background you need to know about how Linux displays images, I leave you another resource [here](https://studiopixl.com/2017-05-13/linux-graphic-stack-an-overview). Basically you have to add the previously collected information to the kernel driver that manages the KMS interface (Kernel Mode Setting, part of the Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) interface.

It will also be important that you supply the kernel with the desired display resolution, among other things, in the kernel argument line.